# Implicit differential of diameter

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

In my physics course there is a problem where the volume "V" of a sphere is filled with a gas. The sphere is released in a liquid, therefore the amount of gas in this volume "V" decreases because of concentration differences. If you evaluate a time dependent mass-balance the following diff. equation is to be solved for the diameter "D(t)", where $\alpha$ is a physical constant.
Boundary conditions are: $D(t=0)=D_{0}$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}D^3(t)=(-24 \pi\alpha) D(t)
$$

I would like to have some help evaluating the $\frac{d}{dt}D^3(t)$ term...

Comment: The derivative of $t \mapsto D^3(t)$ is $t \mapsto 3 D^2(t) D'(t)$. Use this to get an ODE in $D$.

Comment: @INeedyourhelp You can mark a answer as accepted (✓) if you want to show that you appreciate the work of the people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify the above equation as:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(D(t))^3}{\mathrm{d}t}=3(D(t))^2\frac{\mathrm{d}D(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=-24\pi\alpha D(t)$$
Using the chain rule of differentiation.
Now let's simplify it a little more so that it looks like a neat Differential equation:
$$D(t)\;{\mathrm{d}D(t)}=-8\pi\alpha \mathrm{d}t$$
This should be simple to integrate with the boundary conditions given. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @sai-karktik thanks for your help!

Comment: @INeedyourhelp glad I could help ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). The easiest way to remember it is to "expand the fraction":
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}D^3}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}D^3}{\mathrm{d}D}\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}=3D^2\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Comment: Thanks the "expand fraction" trick will come in real handy!

Comment: @INeedyourhelp You're welcome :)

Comment: @INeedyourhelp You can mark the answer as accepted (✓) if you want to show that you appreciate the work of Botond.

Comment: @callculus it would be better if the OP could accept an answer that satisfactorily answers his/her question after some amount of time (maybe ½ hour ?) So that more people can get a chance to answer and then the OP can pick the best.

Comment: @sai-kartik That is right. I just wanted to give the information to the OP that an answer can be accepted. There are too many questions here on MSE which a has no accepted answer although nice answers have been posted.

Comment: @callculus Ahh.. I see..